# Different API key used when manually loading the Google API in google-maps-react

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-react

I'm using manual `Google API` loading, as in the [docs](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react#manually-loading-the-google-api).
A snippet from my index.html:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

where MY_KEY is a hardcoded key which I generated for the project.

However, when using geolocation, by tracing the outgoing requests, I noticed that a different `API key` is used: `AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw` which looks like a generic key as it is floating all around the web.

As a result, most of the time the `API` is unavailable, e.g. at later times of the day it replies with:

```
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
"message": "This API requires billing to be enabled on the project. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=77185425430 to enable billing.",
"extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=77185425430"
```

I have not found this API key in the library code itself nor in the window.google object, so I'm a bit puzzled where does it actually come from...

But most importantly, how can I enforce the use of my key?

**EDIT**:
The same issue is present the demo site: https://fullstackreact.github.io/google-maps-react/
The API key in the source of the page is: `AIzaSyAyesbQMyKVVbBgKVi2g6VX7mop2z96jBo`
While the one being actually used for queries is:

Chrome: `AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw`

Firefox: `AIzaSyD_Drzahe4dBzGCZ9ArvowCvrPx_yFrlCM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's an expected behavior in case of the geolocation service at least. There are standard browser keys being used for those requests.

I haven't found the source of the daily usage limit error, however I'm not observing it anymore in the final version of the app.